# Prevent dirty read in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database, multithreading, transactions

I have a MySQL table

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+--------+
| id | status |
+----+--------+
|  1 |  unread     |
+----+--------+
```

Suppose I am reading this application from Machine m1, m2, m3, m4 which are H.A of each other.

What I want is :

**If** `status == unread`
then any one(but only one) of  m1, m2, m3, m4 can pick up this row changed its status to `processing` and process it further.

But what problem I am facing is of **multiple dirty reads as m1, m2, m3, m4 simultaneously** read `status = unread` and they simultaneously changed status to `processing` and start processing it.

**How can I assure that only one among m1, m2, m3, m4 should read a row at a time**?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why is it about `java` and multithreading, since you are accessing to the DB from different machines, but generally [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) is what you presumably need.

Comment: because I am using java for communicating with MySQL, spring-boot more specific

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you use JDBC you can invoke this construction as well.

Comment: as I am reading from machine m1, m2, m3, m4, will this make sure only one of m1, m2, m3, m4  reads the table, modify its `status` if `status=unread` and process it

Answer (score 0):

The question look likes about the data consistent of bussiness.

There are two approach can resolve the situation.

First,you can use the lock the row data by pessimistic lock when you access data.
Like:

```
select ... from test for update
```

This approach is provided by the database system.

The second is optimistic lock.You should change your table format and you should add a column name `version` that is used identify the current data version.When you update the data,you should check the data version and increase the version.Like following:

```
currentVersion=select version ... from test where ...    //statement1

update status=processing,version=currentVersion+1 where version=currentVersion;    //statement2
```

Look your situation,all over of application will execute statement1 and get currentVersion,and when they execute the statement2, the statement2 will return how many rows has changed.But only one result is large than zero,the others is zero.So you can check it whether zero or not,and depend if execute your bussniess.